# How do I use multiple styles of CSS project files in the Google Apps Script Web application?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script

The task is to reproduce the images as in this example `https://jsfiddle.net/47rm8kwc/`
I took an [example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript) from the documentation google created another file STYLESHEET1 HTML (changed the color). When issuing I see lines of the same color only the last applied style. Tell me how to apply several styles correctly?
Thank you.

```
<?!= include('Stylesheet'); ?>


   <p>First style.</p>

    <?!= include('Stylesheet1'); ?>

    <p>Second style.</p>
```

Comment: Why are you applying the styles in different files? I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jordan Rhea I'm trying to use several styles in one project for this different files.

Comment: But why do your different styles need to be in different files?

Comment: @Jordan Rhea Probably I did not correctly formulate the question. I want to build the styles in one file, but I do not know how to steal it. http://joxi.ru/V2VnO54IxL4Dk2

Comment: Inside of your style sheet file, you should have different class names. And each class name can have different CSS.  [CSS Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) [Class Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)

Comment: @Jordan Rhea Thank you for the link I will study!

Comment: Thank @SandyGood for the link

Comment: @Jordan Rhea All it turned out in one file was enough to wrap all the attributes in the <style>
Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example of one of my html files with styles.  I'm using a google file and some of my own styles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <style>
      #my_block{border:2px solid black;background-color:rgba(0,150,255,0.2);padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      #conv_block{border: 1px solid black;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      .bttn_block{padding:5px 0px 10px 0px;}
      .sndr_block {border:1px solid rgba(0,150,0,0.5);background-color:rgba(150,150,0,0.2);margin-bottom:2px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <div id="my_block" class="block form-group">
      <div class="sndr_block">
        <strong>Sender 1</strong>
        <br /><input type="text" size="30"value="" id="sender1msg" class="action" />
        <br /><div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Send" name="Sender1" id="sender1" class="action" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="sndr_block">
        <strong>Sender 2</strong>
        <br /><input type="text" size="30" value="" id="sender2msg" class="action" />
        <br /><div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Send" name="Sender2" id="sender2" class="action" /></div>
      </div>
      <div id="conv_block"> 
        <strong>Conversation</strong>
        <br /><textarea id="conversation" rows="10" cols="35"></textarea>
        <br /><input type="button" value="Save" name="Save" id="save-msg" class="action" />
        <input type="button" value="Delete" name="Delete" id="del-msg" class="action" />
        <input type="button" class="action" id="disp-log-setting" value="Settings" onClick="google.script.run.logSettings();" />
        <input type="button" value="Refresh" class="action" id="refresh" />
      </div>
      <div id="btn-bar">
        <br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" class="green" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#sender1').click(sendMessage1);
        $('#sender2').click(sendMessage2);
        $('#del-msg').click(deleteConversation);
        $('#save-msg').click(saveConversation);
        $('#refresh').click(refreshConversation);
        google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(updateConversation)
           .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
           .getConversation();
      });

      function sendMessage1()
      {
        var message = $('#conversation').val() + '\nSender1:\n' + $('#sender1msg').val();
        var newconversation = {'thread': message, 'active': true};
        $('#sender1msg').val('');
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "#ffe866");
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateConversation)
          .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
          .savConversation(newconversation);
      }

      function sendMessage2()
      {
        var message = $('#conversation').val() + '\nSender2:\n' + $('#sender2msg').val();
        var newconversation = {'thread': message, 'active': true};
        $('#sender2msg').val('');
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "#ffe866");
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateConversation)
          .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
          .savConversation(newconversation);
      }

      function deleteConversation()
      {
        var conversation = {'thread': '***** Start a new thread *****', 'active': true};
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "#ffe866");
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateConversation)
          .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
          .savConversation(conversation);
      }

      function saveConversation()
      {
        var message = $('#conversation').val();
        var newconversation = {'thread': message, 'active': true};
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "#ffe866");
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateConversation)
          .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
          .savConversation(newconversation);
      }

      function updateConversation(conversation)
      {
        $('#conversation').val(conversation.thread);
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "white");
      }

      function refreshConversation()
      {
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "#ffe866");
        google.script.run
           .withSuccessHandler(updateConversation)
           .withFailureHandler(showStatus)
           .getConversation();
      }

      function showStatus()
      {
        dispStatus('showStatus','This is status');
        $('#conversation').css("background-color", "#ffb3b3");
      }

     console.log('ModeLessDialogJavaScript');
   </script>
   <script>var myVar = setInterval(refreshConversation, 10000);</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just thought you might like to see something simple.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I'm a beginner and I'm still very far from understanding!)) Thank you!